# File not found error for .app file when running logical unit tests in Cocoa Touch

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm get the following error when attempting to run my newly created logical unit tests for cocoa touch (with newly created target for said unit tests):

```
ld: file not found:  /Users/mtford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fggwogwgifttccffwerwbfhoklcf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However this location does exist in my file system:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ mtford$ ls -l /Users/mtford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fggwogwgifttccffwerwbfhoklcf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mtford  staff  3160412 Jun 25 19:10 /Users/mtford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fggwogwgifttccffwerwbfhoklcf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

I'm at my wits end trying to solve this...

**Update**

I found out why Xcode is throwing an error: its looking for:

```
 " /Users/mtford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mosayc-fggwogwgifttccffwerwbfhoklcf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mosayc.app/Mosayc"
```

when running the Ld command. Notice the space at the front? This causes an error in bash. Any ideas where this space could be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

In my target settings under Bundle loader I had  "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp" (notice the space). I removed the space and still didn't work. I removed the quotes as well and then it worked fine!